# What happens when we increment the below typecasted pointer?

Tags: c++

What will happen if we increment a pointer to class which is typecasted to int type?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;
class Hello{
   int x=2;
   int y=3;
 public: 
    void print(){
      cout<<"This is class Hello";
    }
};
int main() {
Hello *h=new Hello();
int *i=(int *)h;
    i++;  //What will i point to?   
}
```

My question is what does i point to once incremented as shown in the above code?

Also I have another doubt-I know memory to a structure in contigious fashion,Is memory assigned in contigious manner to class?
P.S:This question was asked to me in an interview with **Toshiba Software**

Comment: If you are expecting `i` to start pointing at `x` then increment to point at `y` you are going down a dangerous path and you will get burned relying on such behavior

Comment: Don't... just don't.

Comment: `i` doesn't point to an `int`, so you can't do anything with it.

Comment: Please take some time to read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: `i++` is undefined.

Comment: You mean "contiguous". The flu is contagious.

Comment: Also, that breaks [strict aliasing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Strict_aliasing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semi official answer: this is undefined behavior, and **anything** the program does after the increment is fair game. Seriously, anything.

If you do this, run your program and it hacks your bank account, that's okay. It's not violating the way you wrote it.

There is one complication, though. The lives up to the definition of "[PoD](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType)", or "Plain ol' data" (full definition in the link). Such structs are guaranteed to be layed out like C structs. With that in mind, you will likely get it pointing to `y` as you expect, and can even claim that's within the language's specs.

With that said, why #@$&!(@# would you do such a thing? If you two distinct things to reside in the same memory location, use a `union`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, if the compiler can prove the bad code is reached, anything the program does *before* is UB as well.

Comment: The definition of PoD does not, as far as I know, include private members as a criteria. I linked to it in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, yeah. I deleted my comment for that reason. So long as all data members have the same accessibility level, even private, then accessibility won't be a problem.

Comment: I understand why for virtual methods, because of the vtable pointer, but how does it change the layout of the structure if it has a constructor or static member? Static members I thought were in the same memory space as global static members. And the constructor method isn't part of the structure, is it, I mean as far as occupying part of the size of the struct.

Comment: It was a copying error. Read the definition at the link.

Answer (score 1):

This is an undefined behavior.

In practice, the new `i` will point four bytes (`sizeof(int)`) past the beginning of the allocated instance of `Hello` and has many chances to point to `Hello.y`.

This class indeed probably be allocated contiguously. In other cases, alignment constraints can be enforced and result in padding between fields.

Comment: You shouldn't ask such a question here as many respondents hate them. And I shouldn't be answering. ;-)